# Playing ismv file type on native Android player

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to play ismv files on Android media player. I am referring to this link: http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/ where I can get the ismv filetype or media manifest. Could I play this in the native Android media player? When I try to, I get the erro "Cannot play video"

Comment: I fail to see how this is specifically programming related.

Comment: I want to know is it possible to play ismv files on Android media player? Is smooth streaming possible on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid, NO.
I am actually developing a ismv files streaming application, but a special SDK is needed.
For supported formats, refer to the link below.
[Supported Media Formats in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core).